# Dirac spinor for arbitrary momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, dirac-equation, spinors

In many treatments of the Dirac equation (e.g. Peskin and Schroder, pages 45-46) after subbing in $\psi(x) = e^{-ix_\mu p^\mu}u(\vec p)$, with $u$ a constant spinor, into the Dirac equation, we consider the rest frame and, solving for $u$, find:
$$u(0)=\sqrt{m}\begin{bmatrix}
           \xi \\
           \xi
         \end{bmatrix},$$
with $\xi$ an arbitrary two component spinor, and a convenient normalisation. The general $\vec p$ case is then obtained, for example by boosting the above spinor. The result is quoted as 
$$u(\vec p)=\begin{bmatrix}
           \sqrt{p_\mu \sigma^\mu} \xi \\
           \sqrt{p_\mu \bar{\sigma}^\mu} \xi
         \end{bmatrix},$$
with $$\sigma^\mu = (\mathbb{1},\sigma^i) \quad \quad \bar{\sigma}^\mu = (\mathbb{1},-\sigma^i)$$
where "it is understood that in taking the square root of a matrix, we take
the positive root of each eigenvalue". Now,

$$ p_\mu \sigma^\mu = \begin{bmatrix}
           p_0+p_3 & p_1+i p_2 \\
           p_1 - i p_2 & p_0 -p_3
         \end{bmatrix},$$
and the eigenvalues of this matrix are $p_0 \pm |\vec p|$. So am I to understand that
$$\sqrt{p_\mu \sigma^\mu}=\begin{bmatrix}
           \sqrt{p_0 +|\vec p|} & 0 \\
           0 & \sqrt{p_0 -|\vec p|}
         \end{bmatrix}\quad ?$$